# Screen goes insane sometimes after ubuntu 22.04 LTS update?

Tags: screen, flash, lts, bug-reporting

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS . and sometimes the whole screen just flashes.

[image]

[image: image of my screen looks like this]

Everything just starts overlapping each other.
It goes away when you press any key. But I want it gone.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
        Kernel driver in use: i915 Kernel modules: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1) 
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] TU117M
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This is not intended behavior (clearly).  I suggest that you [report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121). Be sure to include details about your hardware. In the meantime, if you are currently using Wayland, you may want to login with X.org instead (or vice versa)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] TU117M
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia