# Screen gets jittery. Artifacts on Screen

Tags: screen, visual-artifacts, 22.10

My sceen get atrifacts suddenly. **How do i fix this**.
I just updated from ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10. I am having this Issue since.

[image]

1
[image]

**How do i fix this**.

Driver
[image]

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] TU117M
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Is it the same thing as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406243/screen-goes-insane-sometimes-after-ubuntu-22-04-lts-update ? If so, which graphics are you using when the problem occurs? Chances are it's faulty hardware.

Comment: No. it is different this time. I updated this time to Ubuntu 22.10. screenshot of driver i am using is above. nvidia geforce gtx 1650

Comment: 1. Nvidia recommends 515, not 510, for a GTX1650, at the time of this writing. 2. This doesn't answer my question above. You have an Intel iGPU and a Nvidia dGPU. Does it happen with one or both? Please open Nvidia X Server Settings and select each profile and reboot and TEST. Please update the question accordingly.

Comment: I experienced something somewhat similar after a routine update to Kubuntu 20.04. Enabling the compositor (which I had been leaving disabled) ended my misery... although that's obviously not a proper fix. I was using Intel, not Nvidia.

Comment: @Ryan This isn't screen tearing, it's much worse.

Comment: Thank you everyone. But I do not have the Problem anymore. I updated to the 515 driver as @ChanganAuto suggested and haven't had the problem since.